# ¿Como exporto un archivo de Excel desde C# (La consulta está en un DatagridView) con un formato en la celdas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Cordial Saludo.
Debo hacer que después de unas consultas desde `C#`, se exporte a **Excel**.
El problema viene cuando tengo unos registros, los lotes de un producto, y por ejemplo existen lotes **004352** pero cuando exporto a **Excel** sale solo **4352**, o sea, salen con formato general.
¿Como hago para que exporte sea el libro completo o columnas en específico como texto?

```
 public void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
    {
        try
        {

            SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
            fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
            fichero.FileName = "ArchivoExportado";
            if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;

                aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
                hoja_trabajo=
                    (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo


                for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if ((grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)
                        {

                            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

                        }
                    }
                }
                libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
                libros_trabajo.Close(true);
                aplicacion.Quit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al exportar la informacion debido a: " + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes asignar el formato usando la propiedad `NumberFormat`, como ser

```
hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].NumberFormat = "@";
```

aunque si conoces la columna podrias aplicar directamente usando

```
cells["A:A"].NumberFormat = "@";
```

[Format an Excel column (or cell) as Text in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067926/format-an-excel-column-or-cell-as-text-in-c)